# Consulta para traer 100 registros en mysql en un hosting pero solo me trae 3 porque sucede esto?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una aplicación en un hosting y al realizar una petición de consulta de 100 registros se queda cargando, pero si solo hay 3 registros en la tabla si me responde sin problemas que me falta por hacer, ya revise el servidor y al parecer esta sin restricciones en cuanto a limites, revise en phpmyadmin pero también veo las capacidades amplias no soy experto en el tema pero los he podido revisar por lo que he encontrado en internet, también ya revise mi consulta de manera localhost y sin problemas me regresa todos los registros solo es una simple consulta:

```
    SELECT productos.id_producto, productos.codigo_producto,productos.nombre_producto,productos.fecha_inicio,productos.fecha_final,productos.presupuesto_horas,
productos.estatus,productos.tiempo_acumulado,departamentos.departamentos,clientes.nombre_cliente,empleados.empleado
FROM proyectos
INNER JOIN departamentos ON productos.iddepartamentopro = departamentos.id_departamentos
INNER JOIN clientes ON productos.idclientepro = clientes.id_cliente
INNER JOIN empleados ON productos.idempleado_responsable = empleados.id_empleado 
ORDER BY id_producto DESC;
```

por que pasa eso que solo al tener 3 registros la tabla si me responde si hay mas se queda cargando?

Answer (score 0):

una disculpa ya vi mi error y por si alguien le sirve esta información era por que el formato de los registros que estaba subiendo en la columna fecha no era el correspondiente, los estaba subiendo sin formato directamente en un insert de sql pero lo intente con archivo .csv y al darle formato en la fecha me permitió y ya me responde correctamente todo.

Saludos!